# Optional OptionsetField is SilverStripe 3.2

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1.* I used some forms with OptionsetFields which are optional, so not required to make a choice. This was working well. But since i updated to SilverStripe 3.2.0 the form doesn't accept this anymore. When submit it comes with a validation message, even if I don't use validation in the whole form.
See this screenshot:

[image]

This is the code of the field:

```
$ClassField = OptionsetField::create('Class', _t('General.CLASS', "Class"), array(
        "S" => "S",
        "E" => "E",
        "U" => "U",
        "R" => "R",
        "O" => "O",
        "P" => "P"
    ));
```

Any idea to make this field optional again in SilverStripe 3.2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 3.2, you have now to tell OptionsetField it can be empty by using [setEmptyString()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-DropdownField.html#_setEmptyString):

```
$ClassField = OptionsetField::create(
    'Class', 
    _t('General.CLASS', "Class"), 
    array(...)
)
->setEmptyString('none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be also interested in the silverstripe-display-logic module, which allows you to display certain fields based on some conditions: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic