# Optional OptionsetField is not working in SilverStripe 3.2

Tags: silverstripe

I have upgraded SilverStripe from version 3.1 to 3.2. Since the upgrade the [event calendar module](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-event-calendar) has stopped working and is showing the following error:

> Please select a value within the list provided. is not a valid option

This error is for the `OptionsetField` on the `CustomRecursionType` variable, but that is not a required field.

This is the code for field:

```
$f->addFieldsToTab("Root.$recursion", array(
    new CheckboxField('Recursion',_t('CalendarEvent.REPEATEVENT','Repeat this event')),            
    new OptionsetField(
        'CustomRecursionType',
        _t('CalendarEvent.DESCRIBEINTERVAL','Describe the interval at which this event recurs.'),
        array (
            '1' => _t('CalendarEvent.DAILY','Daily'),
            '2' => _t('CalendarEvent.WEEKLY','Weekly'),
            '3' => _t('CalendarEvent.MONTHLY','Monthly')
        )

    )

));
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The [SilverStripe Event Calendar module](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-event-calendar) does not work on SilverStripe 3.2 at this point in time. It is still programmed for SilverStripe 3.1. There are a few things that need updating to make it work for SilverStripe 3.2.

One of the main problems is there seems to be a bug in SilverStripe 3.2 where [`OptionsetField` is always a required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732666/optional-optionsetfield-is-silverstripe-3-2). The solution for now is to call `setEmptyString` on each `OptionsetField`.

I am currently working on some updates to the module to make it work with both SilverStripe 3.1 and 3.2. Once I am done I will submit a pull request to be reviewed by the module owner.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At least the recursion is saving now.

Answer (score -1):

In that same class, remove Recursion from the required fields array; and that should do the trick:

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Can you please tell me where to remove Recursion

Comment: You mean from here "$f->addFieldsToTab("Root.$recursion", array(" ?

Comment: No, it's a separate area in most cases inside a method called RequiredFields, or as an array on parameter $required_fields. If you can go to http://www.sspaste.com and copy and paste the entire contents of the file you got the code above from. Provide the link and I'll point it out for you.

Comment: Once again Thank you..

Here is the link
http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/56599c4952573
Can you see once for me?

Comment: Any Suggestions on this for me?

Comment: Okay, so no Required Fields exist on those classes at all, which make me wonder where the they have been configured. Does SilverStripe throw you a specific error message?

Comment: Yes it is saying "Please select a value within the list provided. is not a valid option"

Comment: Or do you want me to put total module code, it may helps?